# Netbeans: C code debug hangs on start

Tags: debugging, netbeans, gdb

When I start debug in Netbeans, nothig happens. Output strings don't apper; Pause, Continue, step buttons are inactive (only Stop debug button and restart button are active). Stack window is empty.

I tried to run process in shell and attach to it by Netbeans debug. Message with caption "Debugger error" appeared, it contained a text: \320\235\320\265\321\202 \321\202\320\260\320\272\320\276\320\263\320\276 \321\204\320\260\320\271\320\273\320\260 \320\270\320\273\320\270 \320\272\320\260\321\202\320\260\320\273\320\276\320\263\320\260.

Project is compiled with -g flag; gdb version is: GNU gdb 7.0.1-debian; Netbeans version is 7.1; In DDD tool debug for this program works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the cause was a bad variable in the Watches. I couldn't delete it while debugging was hanging. So I had to open the variables window manually while not building/debugging (Windows -> Debugging -> Variables). After deleting the bad variable, everything was fine.

Basically I deleted all variables, since I couldn't figure out, why gdb or netbeans disliked something like:
`(char*)_Foo->Bar->Fail`. During the previous debugging run this watch worked fine.